# Insert QUERY Slowdown for CxOracle in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, buffer, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert about 60k records into an Oracle DB using cxOracle from python.
Earlier the records used to inserted very fast, however now it takes about 9m for every 100 records.
I am inserting record by record, so as to capture any failed record for later.

Is the slowdown due to my system memory being full,

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      32146        2920        9218         337       20008       27770
Swap:     0           0           0
```

```
rootuser@<hostname>:~$ tail -f /proc/78673/fd/1
2020-12-30 08:09:35,832 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11100 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 08:18:07,131 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11200 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 08:27:11,816 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11300 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 08:35:41,880 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11400 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 08:44:12,371 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11500 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 08:52:40,005 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11600 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 09:01:41,538 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11700 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 09:10:12,562 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11800 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 09:18:45,239 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 11900 records in GlobalReport
2020-12-30 09:27:15,327 - DEBUG - [insert.py]-[insert_to_db]-[163] - Inserted 12000 records in GlobalReport
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like memory issues from what you have shown. There are some activities that take place on the database server at intervals which may be impeding progress. You can limit this activity by using batch insertion. You can use batch errors to be able to capture failed records for later processing. Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BatchErrors.py). If that still doesn't help, you'll need to engage the services of a DBA or figure out the necessary configuration on your own!

Comment: thanks for the hint on database server part. it was actually **Oracle RecycleBin** full or something. Got "orA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-30667" on inspection and was solved with `purge recyclebin;`